# Use ngspice library in WebAssembly

Tags: c++, c, static-linking, webassembly, emscripten

I would need some help with using ngspice as a library in a webassembly (wasm) project.

I installed emsdk and newest version of emcc (1.39.20) and downloaded the source of ngspice version 32.

To my greatest surprise, I was able to compile ngspice to wasm target by following [this guide](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html):

```
emconfigure  ./configure --with-ngshared --disable-debug
emmake make
```

(I had to patch `configure` a little to pass the checks by adding `.out.js a.out.wasm` to this line:)

```
# The possible output files:
ac_files="a.out a.out.js a.out.wasm conftest.exe conftest a.exe a_out.exe b.out conftest.*"
```

This produced a `libngspice.so.0.0.0` file that I tried to link to from C++ code. However that failed with `duplicate symbol: main`. So it seemed that  `libngspice.so.0.0.0` contained a `main` function, that shouldn't have been there if I understand the purpose of the `--with-ngshared` of the configure script correctly.

So I manually removed the `main` function from `main.c` of ngspice and recomplied using the above method. This time I could successfully complie my own project, linking to ngspice. However when I call `ngSpice_Init`, I recieve the following runtime errors:

```
stderr Note: can't find init file.

exception thrown: RuntimeError: unreachable executed,@http://localhost:8001/sim.js line 1802 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[67]:0x24e9
@http://localhost:8001/sim.js line 1802 > WebAssembly.instantiate:wasm-function[88]:0x423b
...
```

Minimal reproducible steps:

1. compile ngspice as above
2. compile the code below using `em++ -o sim.html sim.cpp lib/libngspice.so`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "sharedspice.h"

using namespace std;


int recieve_char(char * str, int id, void* p){
    printf("recieved %s\n", str);
}

int recieve_stat(char* status, int id, void* p){
    printf("status: %s\n", status);
}

int ngexit(int status, bool unload, bool exit, int id, void* p){
    printf("exit: %d\n", status);
}

int recieve_data(vecvaluesall* data, int numstructs, int id, void* p){
    printf("data recieved: %f\n", data->vecsa[0]->creal);
}

int recieve_init_data(vecinfoall* data, int id, void* p){
    printf("init data recieved from: %d\n", id);
}

int ngrunning(bool running, int id, void* p){
    if(running){
        printf("ng is running\n");
    }else{
        printf("ng is not running\n");
    }
}


int main(){


    ngSpice_Init(&recieve_char, &recieve_stat, &ngexit,
             &recieve_data, &recieve_init_data, &ngrunning, (void*)NULL);

    char** circarray = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 7);
    circarray[0] = strdup("test array");
    circarray[1] = strdup("V1 1 0 1");
    circarray[2] = strdup("R1 1 2 1");
    circarray[3] = strdup("C1 2 0 1 ic=0");
    circarray[4] = strdup(".tran 10u 3 uic");
    circarray[5] = strdup(".end");
    circarray[6] = NULL;
    ngSpice_Circ(circarray);

    ngSpice_Command("run");


    return 0;
}
```

So could someone please help me correctly compiling ngspice library to wasm target?

(Before someone asks, yes, I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872425/linking-error-when-compiling-ngspice-with-emscripten-on-ubuntu), but it didn't help much)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to compile the library and my example code after making several changes to the ngspice source. The patch and a guide on how to compile ngspice to wasm, can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/ngspice/patches/96/).

(The issue leading to the error shown in my question was with the example code, not returning anything from functions that by signature should return `int`. This is not tolerated in wasm.)